# Acquiring YAP without MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, yap

It's a very trivial question, but where I can to download `YAP` without MiKTeX?

I have begun to use TeX Live instead if MiKTeX, however, I want to keep `YAP`.
In TeX Live, there is only `DVIOUT` application.

I didn't find a separate installer for `YAP`.
Do you know where it's possible to get installer just for `YAP`?

Comment: From an existing installation or from [MiKTeX Portable](http://miktex.org/portable). But I do not know, whether this runs without MiKTeX.

Comment: Yap needs at least access to the fonts in the texmf tree as (unlike the pdf-format) dvi doesn't contain them. It also need access to a texmf tree to store font files (pk, tfm) it perhaps has to create. So a standalone installation doesn't make much sense. You could install a basic miktex and attach the texlive texmf roots. But you will probably run into problems with the tools with the same names on both system.

Comment: See this discussion at [LaTeX Community](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=5666) from 2009.

Comment: Yap doesn't render correctly the figures created with graphics or  `Tikz`. (Very bad)

Answer (score 2):

Yap needs at least access to the fonts in the texmf tree as (unlike the pdf-format) dvi doesn't contain them. It also need access to a texmf tree to store font files (pk, tfm) it perhaps has to create. So a standalone installation doesn't make much sense. You could install a basic miktex and attach the texlive texmf roots. But you will probably run into problems with the tools with the same names on both system.