# How can I add YAP to a TexLive installation?

Tags: miktex, texlive, yap

I don't like TeXLive's DVIOUT; I do like MikTeX's YAP... unlike in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168812/5640), I don't want an independent YAP installation - I want to graft it onto TeXLive. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a feature request on TeXLive. Moreover, this request is basically impossible to fulfill.

Comment: @yo': I did not ask that the TeXLive maintainers add YAP, but rather how to add it myself.